# how to set boolean value in spinner android?

Tags: java, android, spinner

I am getting boolean value from the server how to set that value to the spinner and retrieve and send it back to server?

```
               if (true) {
                    spinner.setSelection(1);
                } else {
                    spinner.setSelection(2);
                }
```

how to retrieve the value from the spinner and how to send boolean value to the server, is there any easiest way?

Comment: You can convert it to string and set it to the spinner and same you can send it to the server

Answer (score 0):

As per chirag's comment, you can covert that boolean to index (because you know the value of boolean on the index) and you can covert and sent it to the server.